# Creating Seam 3 Project

Tags: seam, seam3

Its probably a bad question, but i've not found any good tutorial showing how to create a seam 3 project to eclipse. I saw that i need maven, jboss, seam 3, and eclipse helios... then i've downloaded them all but couldn't create the project... also got m2eclipse plugin...
Someone know a good tutorial, or can help creating this project?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 7):

You won't find a tutorial because SEAM 3 isn't a framework like SEAM 2 was.

Seam 3 is a collection of CDI extensions that add functionalities to a Java EE 6 application. Each of these module has it's own documentation. You can check them on [Seam 3 Website](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3).
For instance the Seam Social (which I'm the tech lead) is a bunch of CDI beans to facilitate the integration of social network in a Java EE 6 dev.

A good starting point for using those modules could Be the project [Seam Forge](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/SeamForge) which is a RAD tool to create a Java EE 6 + CDI + Seam 3 application. You should give it a try.